# List VMs /vApps by date of last power-on

Tags: reporting, vmware-vcloud-director

... in vCloud. There's a script [here](http://blogs.vmware.com/PowerCLI/2009/10/when-was-the-last-time-that-vm-was-powered-on.html) to do it for vSphere. Can a similar (or entirely different, I don't care!) approach be used for vCloud?

(The underlying problem is a lot of seldom or never used VMs consuming resources on our vCloud. We'd like to find the barely-used ones and work with the creators to remove them).

Comment: Does your environment have [vCenter Operations Manager](http://www.vmware.com/products/vcenter-operations-manager) installed?

Comment: I'll be honest and say I don't know (I'm a couple of steps removed from the people who need that report). Finding out....

Answer (score 2):

A couple of quick things...

vCloud Director uses vSphere. If there's someone with vCenter access, they can probably run the PowerCLI snippet you linked.

Also, if this is an environment with vCenter Chargeback installed, you can grab some stats from there.

And finally, if you have an option for vCenter Operations Manager, it's handy to be able to glance at the *Reclaimable Waste* dashboard. *Idle* and *Powered Off* VMs are what you'd be looking for.

[image]

Where Idle Virtual Machines are defined as:

Time idle: 90 % 
Detection based on all of the following thresholds:

- Average CPU usage less than: 100 MHz
- Average disk I/O usage less than: 20 KBps
- Average network I/O usage less than: 1 KBps

Comment: Thanks. "Idle and Powered Off VMs " - does that order them by date of last use? We have a LOT of VMs that are legitimately not used very often (it's for experimentation by various teams with our varied products), so just "powered off" isn't telling us too much.

Comment: No, it doesn't list by date of last use.